# Scroll do GridView lento, pesado,

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estou tentando criar um app que seja uma espécie de galeria. Busca as fotos no celular e mostra para o usuário.

O app já está funcionando, mas acontece que o scroll do gridview esta lento.

Não sei mais o que fazer para tentar melhorar a performance. Estou usando LruCache para armazenar as imagens, as imagens são carregadas assíncronas.

Coloquei todos os códigos que acho pertinentes.

GridAdapter

```
package abcde.xyz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Lucas on 25/03/2017.
 */

public class GridImagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {


    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
    public static LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

    public GridImagesAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Integer> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;


        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 4;
        if(mMemoryCache == null){
            mMemoryCache = new LruCache<Integer, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
                @Override
                protected int sizeOf(Integer key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
                }
            };
        }
        mMemoryCache.evictAll();

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            ImageView image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            final Integer item = (Integer)data.get(position);


            image.setImageBitmap(null);
            ImageGridHandler handler = new ImageGridHandler(context, image);
            handler.execute(item);
        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

ImageGridHandler

```
package abcde.xyz;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

/**
 * Created by Lucas on 29/03/2017.
 */

public class ImageGridHandler extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private Context context;
    public ImageGridHandler(Context context, ImageView img){
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(img);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        return loadBitmap(params[0]);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();

        if(imageView != null) {
            //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }


    public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(Integer key, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
            GridImagesAdapter.mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(Integer key) {
        return GridImagesAdapter.mMemoryCache.get(key);
    }

    public Bitmap loadBitmap(Integer resId) {


        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(resId);
        if (bitmap == null) {

           Log.d("ImageGridHandler", "Loading: " + resId);
            if(resId != null) {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                        context.getContentResolver(), resId,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                        null);
                if(bitmap != null) {
                    addBitmapToMemoryCache(resId, bitmap);
                }
            }

            Log.d("GRIDADAPTER", "ImageLoaded");
        }

        return bitmap;
    }


}
```

Layouts

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="umdev.images24.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

     <GridView
         android:id="@+id/gridView"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="0dp"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:columnWidth="100dp"
         android:numColumns="auto_fit"
         android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
         android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
         android:focusable="true"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:fastScrollEnabled="true"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

grid_item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="#fff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

O android possui poucos recursos para exibir as imagens (que geralmente são pesadas). Para resolver esse problema, você deve usar uma biblioteca de processamento de imagens (para poupar trabalho para você). Um exemplo é a [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). A biblioteca gerencia todo o cacheamento/processamento/download de imagens automaticamente.

Na hora de vincular a imagem na imageView através dos seus métodos

```
 image.setImageBitmap(null);
 ImageGridHandler handler = new ImageGridHandler(context, image);
 handler.execute(item); ,
```

você deve usar

```
Glide.with(meuContexto).load(minhaImagem).into(image);
```

onde a variável "minhaImagem" pode ser uma url, um resource ou um bitmap.

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui com essa biblioteca e continua com o mesmo comportamento...

Comment: Outra famosa e o Picasso. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

O problema estava em carregar uma imagem maior que do o ImageView. Neste caso o ImageView tinha que fazer um alterar o tamanho da imagem sempre.

**Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory**

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html